# Change some strings and substrings in Woocommerce using gettext hook

Tags: php, woocommerce, replace, gettext, hook-wordpress

The code I used over the years (example below) hasn't worked for awhile. Tried some other code posted on here, but no joy. It seems WC has changed how to filter/translate and each text changed needs to be separate. Is that correct? Originally had 11 text changes using this code...

Would appreciate some code to perform text changes in WC 5.0 Thanks!

```
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text');
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text');

function translate_text($translated) {
$translated = str_ireplace('Products', 'Prints', $translated);
$translated = str_ireplace('Product', 'Print', $translated);
$translated = str_ireplace('Product Categories', 'Prints', $translated);
return $translated;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress hooks `gettext` and `ngettext` haven't changes since a while and work on translatable strings, work **independently from WooCommerce versions**…

The correct way to make it work with `gettext` and `ngettext` hooks is *(simplifying a bit and adding some missing function arguments)*:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_some_woocommerce_strings', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'ngettext', 'change_some_woocommerce_strings', 10, 3 );
function change_some_woocommerce_strings( $translate_text, $original_text, $domain ) {
    if ( stripos( $original_text, 'Product') !== false || stripos( $original_text, 'Categories') !== false ) {
        $translate_text = str_ireplace( 
            array('Product categories', 'Products', 'Product'),
            array('Prints', 'Prints', 'Print'), 
        $original_text );
    }

    return $translate_text;
}
```

If some strings are not translated, it can be because they have some context added. In this case the hook `gettext_with_context` is required like:

```
add_filter( 'gettext_with_context', 'change_some_woocommerce_strings_with_context', 10, 4 );
function change_some_woocommerce_strings_with_context( $translate_text, $original_text, $context, $domain ) {
    if ( stripos( $original_text, 'Product') !== false || stripos( $original_text, 'Categories') !== false ) {
        $translate_text = str_ireplace( 
            array('Product categories', 'Products', 'Product'),
            array('Prints', 'Prints', 'Print'), 
        $original_text );
    }

    return $translate_text;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Hmmm...neither are working. I put the code in the Neve child theme functions.php In the admin panel it still says 'Products' everywhere, whereas it was Prints, etc. Perhaps the issue is I'm with SiteGround and they removed cpanel & replaced it will what they call Site Tools? Also just noticed WC plugin added a bunch of code to the functions.php. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @Charly For me it works on translatable strings… If strings are not translatable it doesn't work. And this has nothing to do with WooCommerce version as it's related to Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it further to see what's causing it not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that wound up working for me. Change the 2 ibc to the name you want or just leave it. Don't forget to change the name you wish to use instead of Print(s)

```
   add_filter( 'gettext', 'ibc_translate_woocommerce_strings', 999, 3 );

   function ibc_translate_woocommerce_strings( $translated, $untranslated, $domain ) {

     if ( ! is_admin() && 'woocommerce' === $domain ) {

        switch ( $translated ) {

           case 'Products':

           $translated = 'Prints';
           break;

           case 'Product':

           $translated = 'Print';
           break;

           case 'Product Categories':

           $translated = 'Print';
           break;

         // ETC
   
   }

 }   

      return $translated;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can also help.
When you are testing, you should empty the cart before refreshing the page to see the changes. At least this is how it worked for me with the mini-cart widget.
Success to all!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30427611)